# Sending Email (Tell a friend/share link) in Android/iphone using phonegap

Tags: cordova

I have created a mobile application in phonegap and I have to send an email. Can you please give me any idea that how to send the email in android/iphone using phonegap?

Answer (score 3):

Use this plugin https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/EmailComposer

Comment: Thank you very much for your sincere help.

Comment: If satisfied with the answer mark it as correct answer to close this question.